# How to Replace a word in a String with a blank in C#?

Tags: c#, string, replace

Any algorithm which changes a word from a string to a blank?
I'm having problems with this.

my scenario is replacing a word to a blank but some words are also found inside another word so what happens is it also replaces the certain string in that word.

Ex. Hello Ello llo lo o

if I replace llo with **_**

output:
He_**__ E__** ____ lo o

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: output should be Hello Ello _____ lo o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should have some luck with `Regex.Replace` and using the word boundary special character (`\b`) to indicate word boundaries. I'm no expert, though. But do try that.

Example:

```
string input = "llo Hello Ello llo lo o llo, and oh hello llo! Look, a yellow llo.";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\bllo\b", "___");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

```
___ Hello Ello ___ lo o ___, and oh hello ___! Look, a yellow ___.
```

Note this caught the "llo" at the beginning, as well as those followed by punctuation ("llo,", "llo!", and "llo.") without erroneously stripping out those that were part of other words ("Hello", "Ello", "yellow").

---

**Edit**: The following is in response to your comment. My understanding is that you have two TextBoxes, `preview` and `question`, and a ListBox, `chosenwordlist`. I *believe* this is what you want to do:

```
// Start by setting preview to the same text as question.
preview.Text = question.Text;

for (int i = 0; i < chosenwordlist.Items.Count; ++i)
{
    string word = chosenwordlist.Items[i].ToString();

    // Notice the verbatim literal (@) for the SECOND "\b" as well.
    string pattern = @"\b"+ word + @"\b";

    // Since the text in your question TextBox isn't changing, you need to base each
    // replacement off of what's in the preview TextBox, which IS (changing).
    preview.Text = Regex.Replace(preview.Text, pattern, "__________");
}
```

Comment: i have another scenario, there will be a listbox where all of the words from the list that are found in the string will be turned to blank. my code is in a loop where i increments until it reaches the list's total count and it does nothing: preview.Text = Regex.Replace(question.Text, @"\b"+ chosenwordlist.Items[i].ToString() +"\b", "___________");

Comment: @Joseph: You need to make that last string verbatim as well (`@"\b"`).

Comment: @Joseph: Also it looks like that's only going to end up replacing the *last* word in the ListBox in your preview.Text string (because you're overwriting what you did on each iteration). Probably what you want is to set `preview.Text = question.Text`, then do the loop with `preview.Text = Regex.Replace(preview.Text, ...` instead.

Comment: @Dan: what? i dont get it sorry im new.

Comment: ow yeah sorry i forgot. what about making the last string verbatim?

Comment: ow i c just add /b ok thnx dude. your a big help

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions
http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Comment: You can never do too much or enough regex. +1

Comment: My recommendation is to _not_ use regular expressions, quite simply. thecoop introduces a reasonable, expandable, concept (not flawless in its entirety, granted) to the OP which should give enough insight enabling them to achieve what is desired without having to engage a regex engine and/or endure any idiosyncrasies which could result if they did. Obviously this is only my lesser qualified opinion, given my distinguished peers all around.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: The truth is I agree with you in general about regular expressions. They are often hauled out inappropriately for lightweight tasks easily tackled using other tools. However, my comment to thecoop's answer illustrates that it misses some not-so-corner cases, in a way that is easily addressed by regex using word boundaries. In my opinion, this is the fairly rare case where the regex solution is more concise and readable than the alternative, which would be something like thecoop's answer plus a lot of additional logic to detect variations.

Comment: Wow intense Battle!! anyways thnx for your concern guys im newb

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: can you provide solution w/o regexes to this case that really works and has comparable elegance?

Comment: @Dan Tao: Acknowledged and understood, I can concur. @FractalizeR: I don't see you provide anything elegant, let alone a solution, just a link to a reference - to match that elegance all I am required to do is reference the C# specification, right? Maybe just a bad choice of words on your part.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Yea, you're right ;) I wanted to say "of comparable elegance to regexes" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood you correctly. Using Regex you can achieve this:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"(?<![a-z])[a-z](?![a-z])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Debug.WriteLine(myRegex.Replace("test-a-b-c-test", "!"));
```

Will print: `test-!-!-!-test`
From the original string: `test-a-b-c-test`